# Android and PHP : JSON and special characters like è

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8

With my php page I read into an mysql database. The String is in UTF-8 format but if it contain one special character like as **è,à,ù** the json_encode pass null. How can I do ??

Answer (score -1):

use `addslashes()` function in php, it may work

Comment: then you can retrive using htmlentities(), try it